# aqbanking: libchipcard is missing - on Fedora

Tags: fedora, gnucash, finance

I am on Fedora 34.

I use Gnucash and its online banking interface aqbanking. I am trying to get it to interact with my chip card reader. But aqbanking tells me "libchipcard or its plugins" are missing.

I would like to know: where do I find this package, how to install it on Fedora?

---

An Update from January 2024. The package is available by now on Fedora as `libchipcard`. See https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/libchipcard for the history.

Answer (score 1):

Think you'd need to build from source:

```
git clone https://git.aquamaniac.de/git/libchipcard
```

Source: https://www.libchipcard.de

Comment: yes, I intuitively went for this approach as well. But building it and the other 2 packages from source, and using make install to get them into my system, gets me an unfortunate result: as soon as libchipcard is accessed, aqbanking crashes